# What can cause EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in dyldbootstrap?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Porting a bigger project to iPhone i have it running in the simulator, but trying to run it on a iPad device results in a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`in dyld code with the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x2fe01088 in __dyld__ZN13dyldbootstrapL30randomizeExecutableLoadAddressEPK12macho_headerPPKcPm ()
#1  0x2fe06a72 in __dyld__ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_ ()
#2  0x2fe06d3c in __dyld__ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPFPKc17dyld_image_statesjPK15dyld_image_infoEE8allocateEmPKv ()
#3  0x2fe0b398 in __dyld__ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeIPK11ImageLoaderEE8allocateEmPKv ()
#4  0x2fe05fa6 in __dyld__ZN4dyld11removeImageEP11ImageLoader ()
#5  0x2fe06506 in __dyld__ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_ ()
#6  0x2fe0128c in __dyld__ZN13dyldbootstrapL30randomizeExecutableLoadAddressEPK12macho_headerPPKcPm ()
#7  0x2fe01060 in __dyld_branch_to_lookupDyldFunction ()
```

This is building for `iPhone Device 3.2` with the architectures `armv6 armv7` and happens before `main()` is ever entered.

I am currently at a loss for how to find the cause of this, any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought: is there a more detailed error if you use NSZombies?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with ipad when it was compiled originally in a more up to date version of xcode than I had.

It worked in simulator but when debugging on device is crashed out horribly. When unplugging the device however it worked. Solution for me was to update xcode.

If you are having the same problem then try running it on the device without the debugger (Install let it crash then unplug and run it again).

Comment: +1 for a good tip: I did end up upgrading and using a newer base sdk last week and for some reason it worked. Would still be nice to know where this is actually coming from :/